# SQL query get random number of records from two categories

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

Numbers

```
id type_id
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 1
5 2
6 2
7 1
8 1
9 2
```

etc...

I need to get 3 random records of type 1 and the same number of random records of type 2. How can I get it with one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(select * from your_table where type_id = 1 order by rand() limit 3)
union all
(select * from your_table where type_id = 2 order by rand() limit 3)
```

Comment: Just that I have to get random values

Comment: I need to get something like this:
(select * from your_table where type_id = 1 ORDER BY RAND() limit 3)
union all
(select * from your_table where type_id = 2 ORDER BY RAND() limit 3)

Comment: Then use exactly that :)

Answer (score 0):

**Using MySQL**

```
SELECT <<columns>> FROM <<table_name>>
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT <<count>>
```

**Using Oracle**

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM <<table_name>> ORDER BY     
SYS.DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) WHERE ROWNUM <<Count>>
```